Range between min and max values in pandas using lamda
I am trying to get the difference between min and max values after applying a group by. I would like capture the difference in column titled Range in the output dataframe
This is my input:
boyorgirl  testscore
      Boy         34
     Girl         56
      Boy         65
     Girl         76
      Boy         43
     Girl         45
      Boy         67
     Girl         90
      Boy         89
     Girl         45
      Boy         23
     Girl         56
      Boy         67
     Girl         77
      Boy         88
     Girl         35
      Boy         40

Expected output:
         mean  sum  min  max Range
Boy   57.3333  516   23   89    66
Girl  60       480   35   90    55

Code used:
df3 = df.groupby(['boyorgirl']).agg({
    'testscore': ["sum", "max", "mean", lamda x: x.max()-x.min()]

But not getting the range as expected from the lamda function.

This code has some typos. Please [edit] to fix it.

If I fix the typos, the result is exactly as expected, though the title isn't "Range"; is that the problem? Please [edit] to clarify what you mean by "not getting the range as expected". Make sure this is a [mre]; for specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Also check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Potential duplicate: Naming returned columns in Pandas aggregate function?

Title of difference can be anything df3=df.groupby(['boyorgirl']).agg({'testscore':["sum","max","mean", lamda x: x.max()-x.min()]})
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

"lamda" needs to be lambda. There are multiple ways to spell the Greek letter, but only one way to spell it in Python.

Thanks, it works now.  sum max       mean <lambda_0>
boyorgirl
Boy             516  89  57.333333         66
Girl            480  90  60.000000         55


lamda to lambda
Named aggregation (Range)

df3 = (pd.DataFrame(data)
          .groupby('boyorgirl')['testscore']
          .agg(['mean', 'sum', 'min', 'max'])
          .assign(Range=lambda x: x['max'] - x['min'])
          .reset_index())

